# Chrome processes are still running after ChildProcess.kill()

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

I'm trying to launch Chrome via child_process.spawn in NodeJS but when I kill it using ChildProcess.kill(), the browser was closed but there were still some processes running, but when I pass "--no-sandbox" when spawn, that problem didn't happend.
I'm using Windows 11.